# IRibbonExtensibility GetCustomUI not called

Tags: outlook, ms-office, ribbon, extensibility

I'm developing a shared add-in for Outlook.

One of my customers is experiencing trouble on his machine, he does not see my add-in buttons/ui in the main window ribbon.

After exploring his environment and my logs I noticed that the function "GetCustomUI" of interface IRibbonExtensibility is not being called in his environment.

I'm not sure what can be the cause for the different behavior, why doesn't Outlook call the GetCustomUI on the customer machine?

Also - Is it possible to initiate a call to this method by myself? or maybe refresh the ribbon so it will call GetCustomUI?

If anyone has an idea, please help.

Comment: You can try File-> Options->Advance Options-> Show add-in user interface error.

Comment: No, you can't initiate a call yourself. Are you sure the add-in is loaded? Is it a .NET add-in? VSTO? C++?

Comment: I have the same issue.  VSTO add-in. Only GetCustomUI is not being called on my dev PC.

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Seems that when my derived class has template arguments GetCustomUI does not get called at all.

Answer (score 2):

I had same problem. It seems the class implementing IRibbonExtensibility should be defined with ComVisible(true) attribute. Like this:

```
[ComVisible(true)]
public class Ribbon : IRibbonExtensibility {
...
}
```