# VSTO Addin disable builtin outlook button on Appointment (Recurring)

Tags: vsto, outlook-addin, ribbonx

I am developing an Outlook Addin (VSTO, C#). I created the Addin with the following steps in VS: New->Project , then

[image]

From all what I learned in the meantime I fear that this DOES NOT create a COM-AddIn. But all tutorials listed below refer to COM AddIns.

I am looking for a step by step tutorial of how I can disable the builtin OUtlook Button which converts an appointment into a recurring appointment.
I already read a lot about fluent ribbons, like here

- [Programmaticaly disable existing button in outlook compose window ribbon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43579868/programmaticaly-disable-existing-button-in-outlook-compose-window-ribbon)
- https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/office/vba/library-reference/concepts/overview-of-the-office-fluent-ribbon

But I am just no able to put this into action for my purpose:

1.) I implemented in my Addin Class

```
public partial class ThisAddIn : Office.IRibbonExtensibility
```

...

```
 string Office.IRibbonExtensibility.GetCustomUI(string RibbonID)
        {

            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
```

I set the breakpoint on the Exception. But running the addin (in Debugger) never stopped at that point.
I tried what is mentioned here: 
[IRibbonExtensibility GetCustomUI not called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15810829/iribbonextensibility-getcustomui-not-called)
I added [ComVisible(true)] to the VSTO AddIn Class. Does not work either.  I also made sure that the Addin is still loaded.

2.) I am not sure how I could that with Outlook. It says that Outlook has several xml files (one per inspector?)

3.) I am not sure whether I would be able to dynamically change the buttons. Athough the second tutorial talks about that, but i am not sure if callbacks are the right concept here, because my application activley wants to decide when a button should be active/inactive, so there is no waiting for a callback to happen?

I know that the links provided above contain step-by-step tutorials. But there are just too many open questions to these tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

You have already found a complete guide on how to repurpose a ribbon button. Just use `command` tag with the `getEnabled` attribute defined in your ribbon XML markup. For example:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui" onLoad="Ribbon_Load">
  <commands>
    <command idMso="Permissions"  getEnabled="OnGetEnabled" />
  </commands>
 </customUI>
```

You can repurpose built-in ribbon controls, see [Temporarily Repurpose Commands on the Office Fluent Ribbon](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/walkthrough-creating-a-custom-tab-by-using-the-ribbon-designer?view=vs-2019) for more information.

VSTO provides two ways of customizing the Fluent UI:

- [Walkthrough: Create a custom tab by using the Ribbon Designer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/walkthrough-creating-a-custom-tab-by-using-the-ribbon-designer?view=vs-2019)
- [Walkthrough: Create a custom tab by using Ribbon XML](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/walkthrough-creating-a-custom-tab-by-using-ribbon-xml?view=vs-2019)

Unfortunately, the UI designer doesn't support all the features of the Fluent UI. So, you need to stick with a raw XML markup described in one of the articles mentioned above.

Comment: but still the GetCustomUI does not get called?

Comment: Did you follow the steps described in the article mentioned?

Comment: sure, i think the problem is that i created a vsto plugin using vs 2017 . and this causes that the addinis not a com addin

Comment: it doesn't matter which VS version was used.

Comment: If you need to ask a different question I'd suggest posting a new one separately.